# How to link CSS files in magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9

Please anyone tell me how to link css files in magento 1?
I don't no where can I need to add the link ref file please tell me thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You need to add below script in your active theme page.xml file
path:

```
app\design\frontend\yourtheme\default\layout\page.xml




<action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/filename.css</stylesheet></action>
```

Then you add CSS file in the following catalog:

```
skin\frontend\yourtheme\default\css\filename.css
```